# Unix, search for string in multiple files. ( Case sensitive, and accept if the string is in a string )

Tags: linux, bash, unix, xargs, gnu-findutils

I've been using this command:

```
find /path~ -type f | xargs grep -iR STRING1
```

to find strings in multiple files, but i was wondering me how can i find a string in multiple files, Case Sensitive, and even if the string is in other string.

For example:

I'm searching for: Encoder

- if a file contains: `abcdEncoder` — should appear
- if a file contains: `abcdencoder` — shouldn't appear
- if a file contains: `encoderEncoder` — should appear

Maybe the question is a duplicate, but i haven't find it!

Comment: Please note that `find` without `-print0` combined with `xargs` often ends in frustration at a later point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `-i` switch to make the matches case-sensitive.  Your command already searches multiple files and doesn't care whether the string is inside another string, so that'll give you what you want.

Also note that using both `find -type f` and `-R` is redundant: as `-type f` ensures `find` will only print normal files for `grep` to examine, the `-R` (recurse through directories) option won't change anything.  Alternatively, you can use `-R` to get rid of `find` and `xargs`: `grep -R STRING1 /path~`